# background-size: cover - не правильно работает на мобильных девайсах

Tags: css3, адаптивная-верстка

Здравствуйте, уважаемые знатоки!
Такая проблемка: на некоторых мобильных девайсах, фон прорисовывается не полностью...

```
    .header {
  height: 565px;
  background: url(/style/client/img/bg.png)no-repeat top center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

скрин: http://prntscr.com/781vxs
В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте такой варинат

```
.header {
    background: url(...) no-repeat top center; 
    -webkit-background-size: 100%; 
    -moz-background-size: 100%; 
    -o-background-size: 100%; 
    background-size: 100%; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover; 
    -moz-background-size: cover; 
    -o-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

У меня заработало после того как я убрал свойство `background-repeat: no-repeat;`
В принципе оно и не нужно при `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 1):

Обычно такое происходит, когда используется width: 100% у фоновой картинки или у родительского элемента. Т.к. такая ширина будет рассчитана на основе ширины экрана на устройстве в вашем случае.

На странице у вас видимо есть элемент, у которых width больше чем 100% (ширина экрана) и есть возможность прокрутить контент влево/вправо (может быть лишний padding или margin стоит, или фиксированная ширина у какого-то элемента есть).

Чтобы от этого избавиться добавьте min-width для фона равную минимальной ширине, которую хотите установить, или поправьте элементы, которые вылезают.